# Navigating to other page using angularjs with Bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

I am now learning `angularjs` and bootstrap for my new web application. I want to navigate from 1 page to other, i have written the script accordingly. But its not working. Would you people please suggest me the best way to do it?

```
var myDemoApp = angular.module('myDemoApp', ['ui.router']);

    myDemoApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider)
        {
          var home=
          { 
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'pages/Home.html',
          },

          gallery=
          {
            url: '/gallery',
            templateUrl: 'pages/gallery.html',
          },

          logout=
          {
            url: '/logout',
            templateUrl: 'pages/login (2).html',
          };


    $stateProvider

       .state('home', home)

       .state('gallery', gallery)

       .state('logout', logout);

}]);
```

this is my script. Any mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECJN6ENFJszxR7xoIMga?p=preview)

Just a bit adjusted solution above and it is working:

```
var app = angular
  .module('myDemoApp', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

      var home = {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'pages/Home.html',
      },

        gallery = {
          url: '/gallery',
          templateUrl: 'pages/gallery.html',
        },

        logout = {
          url: '/logout',
          templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
        };


     $stateProvider    
      .state('home', home)    
      .state('gallery', gallery)    
      .state('logout', logout);

    }
  ])
```

So, what we can see, there is new default navigation:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

And also changed *not so well formatted* logout template name:

```
templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECJN6ENFJszxR7xoIMga?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks buddy.. is it possible to inject the complete html page? And how do i write it in HTML? And thanks for th edit :)

Comment: Do you mean templates to be loaded as html? not as part of the script? Check the updated version (close the current first) - http://plnkr.co/edit/ECJN6ENFJszxR7xoIMga?p=preview

Comment: ? your stuff is not working? then check my http://plnkr.co/edit/ECJN6ENFJszxR7xoIMga?p=preview which **is working**. Hope it helps